# How to allocate maximum of two ids within a time frame jodatime

Tags: java, jodatime

This is a programming question as I can understand. Context is below -

There is TimeWindow i.e. from 11:00 to 13:00 hours.
I have a list of Ids to be distributed in the next few days but between the specified time window only.

I am using a random number generator for getting random number. I am using JodaTime Api for date time calculation.

As for ex. from Today onwards I had to distribute the Ids in next few days. 
First random generated is 99. so the time allocated for first Id is 16 January 2014, (11:00+99mins)= 12:39 mins. 
Now suppose it would generate 110 as random number. Now ( 12:39+ 110) > greater than 13:00 hours of same day. So it should allocate next day time starting from 11:00 hours. Thus We have distribute all the Ids in the list in next few days.

I am stuck here

```
int[] startHour= {11, 0}; 
int[] endtHour= {13, 0};
DateTimeZone dtZoneforUser = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
DateTime dtNow = DateTime.now(dtZoneforUser);

DateTime dtTimeWindowStart = new DateTime(dtNow.getYear(),dtNow.getMonthOfYear(),dtNow.dayOfMonth().get(),startHour[0],startHour[1],dtZoneforUser);
DateTime dtTimeWindowEnd = new DateTime(dtNow.getYear(),dtNow.getMonthOfYear(),dtNow.dayOfMonth().get(),endtHour[0],endtHour[1],dtZoneforUser);

List<String> lstAudio  = new ArrayList<String>();
lstAudio.add("1");
lstAudio.add("2");
lstAudio.add("3");
lstAudio.add("4");

DateTime recurringStartingTime = dtTimeWindowStart;
DateTime recurringEndTime = dtTimeWindowEnd;
List<String> timeToPlay = new ArrayList<String>();
int daysCounter = 0;
for (String audioVal : lstAudio) {
    int randomNum = DateTimeFormatTestIntellix.getRandom();

    DateTime tempTime = recurringStartingTime.plusMinutes(randomNum);
    recurringStartingTime = tempTime;

    System.out.println(randomNum);

    if ( tempTime.isBefore(recurringEndTime) )
    {
        System.out.println("Audio Id is "+audioVal + " and the play time is "+tempTime);
    }

}
```

Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: I would use the time (as the time is unique) and a counter for that time period.  You can combine them to give you a unique id.

Comment: sorry I did not understand. Please could you explain as Code.

Comment: What is the purpose of this random distribution as it is unclear what real world problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: it is all about allocating a random time based in preference time window from starting days to next few days till all the ids last in the idList.

Comment: Is this just an academic exercise?  Can you explain what the real world problem is that you are trying to solve?

Comment: For example, why not allocate all the ids in the same two hours. It appears you can have 121 unique by minute.

Comment: What is the range of getRandom()?

Comment: it is 20-120. It is not an academic exercise.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Hi  I am able to solve it. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: If it is not academic exercise, I don't understand why you can't explain what you are trying to achieve.  The reason I ask is I suspect there is a much simpler solution if you started with the real problem rather than jump to a solution and try to find a way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to break down the time into portions of the two hour period and days.

```
int period = 2 * 60;
int start = 0;

for (String audioVal : lstAudio) {
   int randomNum = DateTimeFormatTestIntellix.getRandom();
   start += randomNum;

   int days = start / period;
   int timeInDay = start % period;
   // turn the days and timeInDay into a DateTime
}
```